# How can I read from BigQuery and save a csv to Google cloud storage using Dataflow beam/python/Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I see a lot of tutorials and samples for reading into BigQuery from Cloud Storage files, however, I need to read from BigQuery once a day and save the output to a new csv file in cloud storage using Dataflow. Could someone point me in the right direction?

I'm using Apache Beam with Python in a Jupyter notebook. So far, I can run a SQL query to get the data I need but I'm not sure what the best approach is to writing that out to a CSV in Cloud Storage.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you will find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52934251/7903159
However, if you need to save the whole table you can look into [BigQuery Export](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data) and skip Apache Beam.

Comment: Hi, could be useful if you share how you are trying to execute this task and if you are getting some error message, I recommend you take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask